# Redirecting paginator->sort to the first page in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, syntax, sorting, pagination, paginator

How do I do a paginator sort and also specify it to go to the first page:

echo $paginator->sort('Make', 'Car.make');

If you're on page 6 and want to sort the list by car make.  It sorts the list but puts you on page 6 of the sorted list. When someone clicks on the sort by "make" button, I want the paginator to take them to page 1 of the sort.  I know there is an options['url']['page'] variable and that the sort function can be 'sort($title, $key = NULL, $options = array())'. However, I have no idea what the proper syntax is for setting that flag in the $paginator->sort statement above. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Digging through the [PaginatorHelper](http://api12.cakephp.org/class/paginator-helper) [API](http://api12.cakephp.org/class/paginator-helper#method-PaginatorHelpersort) a bit, this should work:

```
echo $paginator->sort('Make', 'Car.make', array('url' => array('page' => 1)));
```

Haven't tested it though.

Comment: I tried this beforehand and it didn't work. It would still stay on page 6.

Comment: Hmm, just tried it and it works for me. Cake 1.2.5. Care to post your code that doesn't work?

Comment: Ok it works now.  Not sure why.  Perhaps I didn't cut and paste correctly.  However, there is still another issue.  On the same page I have a form submit.  Basically you can fix refine your search and submit.  I'm havin the same issue.  When you do a $form->end();  The page loads with new search criteria, but the paginator keeps it on page 6 (for example).  How do I get the form submit to tell the paginator to go to page 1?